# Change form_open path (CodeIgniter)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, codeigniter

I have a simple form here,

```
<?php echo form_open('moneyexchange/invest_first_page');  ?>
     <input id="amount" value="" type="text" placeholder="Amount in &euro;"  name="writtenamount"/>
     <button class="btn btn-lg" type="submit" id="yourbuttonid" >Invest</button> 
     <button class="btn btn-lg" type="submit" id="yourbuttonid2">Borrow</button>
<?php echo form_close();?>
```

What I want to do is on submit of each button, I want to change the path of the form, if I press submit on **Invest** button, it goes to this path `moneyexchange/invest_first_page` , and I need it to change paths when I click the **Borrow** button, since I am using one input field for both. Right now it works only when I click invest. Do tell me in details steps please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use jquery and do this.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $('#yourbuttonid').click(function() { 
        $.ajax({
            url: 'moneyexchange/invest_first_page',
            method: 'POST',
            data: { writtenamount: $("#amount").val()},
            success: function (result) {
              // do stuff
            }
        });  
    });
</script>
```

Do the same for the other button, but in your script just change the id to yourbuttonid2

Answer (score 2):

When you click on Borrow, the below function will be called.You can do something similarly.

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#yourbuttonid2").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var selectedMark = $("#id").val(); //get value here
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'GET',
                    cache:false,
                    timeout:10000,
                    async:true,
                     url: "<?php echo base_url().'controller/function_name' ?>",
                    data:{'val1':selectedMark,'val2':val},
                    success:function(response)
                    {


                    },
                   error:function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown )
                    {
                    console.log(textStatus);
                        alert(textStatus);
                    console.log(errorThrown );
                    }

                });
        });

    });
</script>
```

Comment: Hey one more thing, what about the input field values, how will you take those ?

Comment: either you can pass it through the url or else, you can mention it as `data:{your values}`

Comment: so basically can I write it in this way ? 
data: { writtenamount: $("#amount").val()},

Comment: And what do I have to change in the form ?

Comment: @farhana-you can assign your retrieved data like this -` var selectedMark = $("#id").val(); ` and then you can just write the variable inside the data.

Answer (score 2):

What I would do, is catch the click event for the submit button and check, what its id or classname or content is and then change the form path. After you have changed the form path, you can trigger submit for the form.

In (pseudo) code:

```
$('.btn-frm').click(function(e){ //this is common to all submit btns in the form
  e.preventDefault(); //this stops the form from submitting

  var btnId = $(this).attr('id') //get the btn id

  if(btnId == 'investidname'){
    //change form action invest, could use $('formid').attr('action', 'pathtoend');
  }else if(btnId == 'borrowname'){
   //change form action borrow, could use $('formid').attr('action', 'pathtoend');
  }

  $('#formid').submit();//since, we have changed the path, submit it
});
```

attached jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4ueokvL4/2/

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks, Now I know 3 ways of doing it, all the three answers including yours work :D

Comment: hey I tried doing it, but I guess I made some errors writing the code, can you show me how to write it using my codes?

Comment: @Farhana, do you have a fiddle/jsbin for me to look at?

Comment: Actually the code I posted, thats the only code I wrote, only thing I want to do is change the path written on the form, if you could those information and write it in your answer

Comment: @farhana, I have included jsfiddle in the answer.

Comment: @JeremyRajan why did you comment out the submit part in js fiddle?

Comment: @farhana, because the submit wont in jsfiddle. you can uncomment in your application. there is no point in adding right